# How to show data in list using twitter bootstrap.js & data from collection of model in backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, backbone-views

I am trying to create a simple page using backbone.js and bootstrap.js. I am unable to understand how to play with view of backbone.js so that I have my entire collections of model to represent as a list in bootstrap. I tried searching lot of articles on net but couldn't find something easy that I can understand. Can you please suggest some blog or article on how to do following:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        Boys = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults : {
            Name : '',
            Age : ''
            }
        });

        GardeA = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model : Boys,
            url : http://localhost:8080/getGradeAData,
        });

        GradeAView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '.container .span12',
            initialize: function(){
                gradeA = new GardeA();
                gradeA.fetch();
                this.render();
            },
            render: function(){ 
                //How can I assign the model collection here
                //directly to render in the below bootstrap html page can you please help
                this.$el.html('List of students');
            }
        });
        gradeAView = new GradeAView();
</script>

<div class="container"> 
    <div class="hero-unit">Loading</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <h3>Projects: </h3>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
                    <!-- need to show list of students here-->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed your code (but not tested yet) ..

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        Boys = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults : {
            Name : '',
            Age : ''
            }
        });

        GardeA = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model : Boys,
            url : http://localhost:8080/getGradeAData,
        });

        GradeAView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '#list-of-grade-a-students',
            initialize: function(){
                this.gradeA = new GardeA();
                this.gradeA.fetch();
                this.listenTo(this.gradeA, "sync", this.render);
            },
            render: function(){ 
                //lets generate html
                html = ""
                for (var i = 0; i < this.gradeA.length; i++) {
                     student = this.gradeA.at(i)
                     html += "<li> student name: " + student.get("name") + " </li> "
                }
                //lets add that html to view's element
                this.$el.html(html);
            }
        });
        gradeAView = new GradeAView();
</script>

<div class="container"> 
    <div class="hero-unit">Loading</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <h3>Projects: </h3>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" id="list-of-grade-a-students">
                    <!-- need to show list of students here-->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Some important points:

- Added `id` to your `ul` element where the list of students have to go. Every view should have the parent element as there `el`
- `render` method is not some magical thing. You need to create the html in it and then add it to DOM using `.html()` (or in some cases `.append()` )
- if you call `render` right after `fetch` then you have no gurantee that the collection have been fetched from the server. fairly possible that when render is called, you haven't fetched a thing from server. so we use `listenTo` to bind the view to collection's `sync` event with your render method. This will ensure that the render is called whenever the collection is successfully synced with server

Comment: thanks!!! It worked just one correction, I had to remove 'this' reference for the GradeA collection it was giving me error after I removed it worked..